# How do I select rows that their relationship models attribute is equals true in Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a the model `Cart` with the attributes `id`, `clientIp`, `completed`. I have another model that called `Item`. `Item` Model has a `belongsTo` relationship to `Cart` Model. and the `Cart` Model has `hasMany` relationship to `Item` model. so far so good.

How can I fetch all the `$items` that their `$cart->completed` is true?

I'm really sorry if I haven't explained well my question, I tried my best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this..

```
$items = Item::whereHas('cart', function($q) { 
                 $q->where('completed', '=', 'true')
              })->get();
```

Comment: What about the relationship to the Cart?

Comment: This code is referring to the cart relationship in whereHas method

Comment: Here item will be returned if the related cart is completed, but the cart model will not be attached with the item. if you want to retrieve the cart also, then use `with('cart')` with the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Item::whereHas('cart', function($query) {
    $query->where('completed', true);
})->get();
```

You are simply saying:

```
Give me the items which have a cart that it's completed attribute is true.
```

In the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) there is an example with posts and comments.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

This query will get all the posts that have a comment like `foo*`.